Python Selenium: unable to find element with find_element(By.LINK_TEXT)
I'm fairly new to selenium and HTML and am having trouble locating an element via By.LINK_TEXT. Unfortunately, the webpage I'm accessing requires credentials, so I cannot provide the link. To make up for it this is the full XPath:
/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[3]/a

Below is the relevant HTML
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
            <li><a ng-href="#/customReports/{{viewCtrl.holder.Report.Id}}/edit" ng-if="viewCtrl.canEdit(viewCtrl.holder.Report) && viewCtrl.holder.Report.IsSaved">Edit</a></li>
            <li><a ng-click="viewCtrl.duplicate(viewCtrl.holder.Report)" ng-if="viewCtrl.holder.Report.IsSaved">Duplicate</a></li>
            <li><a ng-click="viewCtrl.export(viewCtrl.holder.Report)">Export</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="viewCtrl.deleteReport(viewCtrl.holder.Report)" ng-if="viewCtrl.canDelete(viewCtrl.holder.Report) && viewCtrl.holder.Report.IsSaved">Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

I'm trying to click the link with the link text: "Export". However, whenever I attempt to find the element, I get the error:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Export"}

The Driver is: driver = webdriver.Chrome()
I have tried:
    driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"Export")
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[contains(text(),'Export')]')
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[3]/a')

Any help or advice is much appreciated

Have you checked to see if the element is in an IFRAME or shadow-root? Have you tried adding a WebDriverWait for clickable? Your first locator looks fine. The XPath using contains(), I would change * to a to be more specific. I would never use an XPath that started with /html, had that many levels, or used that many indices because it's going to be very brittle (break on minor page changes).

I have checked for IFRAMEs and shadow-roots and have found none, WebDriverWait is in my code, I just didn't feel it was necessary to the issue. Unfortunately neither solution worked and I really appreciate your advice about the XPath. I think I have discovered another error, preventing the location of the element. If I am unable to solve it I'll post another question. Thank you for your help!
